# How to display the Code coverage result using Index.html on VSTS\TFS 2017 Build Summary?

Tags: code-coverage, azure-pipelines, cobertura, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a build definition that runs grunt build and generates code coverage results using cobertura tool in **cobertura.xml** files. The cobertura.xml is used in Publish code coverage result task to **publish code coverage result** on VSTS build summary.

Along with **cobertura.xml** file, I have one **Index.html** file present in same folder which also contains code coverage result in detail. I want to call Index.html file using publish code coverage result task to display code coverage result on build summary instead of cobertura.xml.

I tried doing that by passing the name of index.html along with its path in the publish task but it fails.

Is there any way by which I can display the code coverage using index.html?